# Hiding the STL container implementation by returning an iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

What I am trying to do, is return a ForwardIterator(or even a pair of begin and end iterators), so that the uderlying implementation can be kept hidden from a client class.
I was not able find any such example.

if underlying implementation is vector, the iterator is vector::iterator.. Even if you templatize the output , this does not seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not seem to work"? Please be more precise.

Comment: Can you show some code. It is difficult to guess whats wrong from your description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simultaneously return an object as is and expect the caller not to know its type.  The typical way to "hide" the real type of any object is to hide it behind an interface.

For example, you might want to write something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Cursor
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    virtual ~Cursor () {}
    virtual bool has_result () = 0;
    virtual value_type get_result () = 0;
};

// implements cursor interface for any sequence
// described as a pair of forward iterators.
template<typename I>
class ForwardSequenceCursor :
    public Cursor<std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type>
{
    I myCurrent;
    const I myEnd;
public:
     ForwardSequenceCursor(I begin, I end)
         : myCurrent(current), myEnd(end)
     {}
     virtual bool has_result () {
         return myCurrent != myEnd;
     }
     virtual value_type get_result () {
         return *myCurrent++;
     }
};
```

Then, you can return any forward sequence as:

```
class Foo
{
    std::vector<int> myValues;
public:
    std::unique_ptr< Cursor<int> > values () {
        return std::unique_ptr< Cursor<int> >(
            new ForwardSequenceCursor<vector<int>::const_iterator>(
                myValues.begin(), myValues.end()
            )
        );
    }
};
```

And use it like so:

```
std::unique_ptr< Cursor<int> > cursor = foo.values();
while (cursor->has_result()) {
    std::cout << cursor->get_result() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is "type erasure for iterators."  E.g., see one of:

- http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/start_page.html
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/range/detail/any_iterator.hpp

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly do what you're trying to do, because as others have mentioned, if your client is going to get a return value, it needs to know what that return value is.

One way around it is to do something like this:

```
template<typename Collection> class MyClass
{
    typedef Collection::iterator ReturnIt;
    typedef std::pair<ReturnIt, ReturnIt> IteratorPair;
    ReturnIt foo();
    IteratorPair bar();
};
```

Now, this does not free us from clients seeing the container type, but the interface is not bound to the container type.

Answer (score 0):

ForwardIterator is a concept, not a type. You need to declare your function to return a type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no base class of type "ForwardIterator", the normal STL way is to have a typedef to an actual iterator type in your class so that client code can use it like this:

> MyClass::iterator it = myclass.begin();

Not very good as hiding goes, but still lets you change implementation later on without having to change client code.